# How to adjust a div with a dynamic div above it to in the remaining height?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4, flexbox

[image: Basic Layout]

I have a `div1` which is dynamic in height and a `div2` with a scrollable table inside it.

I want the `div2` to occupy the remaining height of the window. Also I want all the divs to be responsive at the same time.

Currently I am using JavaScript to get the window height and calculating the height every time the window loads or is resized, but it isn't working as expected, sometimes it's causing issues.

Comment: Please post your code.  Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please find the fiddle for the same 'https://jsfiddle.net/k5rg1fej/3/'. I hope this might help you understand my query.

Comment: Also, i just want a scroll inside the side bar and the table and no where else on the page

Comment: Thank you for that code but I don't see the javascript you tried.  You say "Currently I'm using javascript..." but you didn't include that in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes i didn't include that . I want an alternate solution because definitely the calculation in js isn't giving me the desired output. The js part is just fetching the different elements by id and based on window height assigning a height to the elements.

Comment: And what is wrong with that?  What do you mean by "sometimes" it causes issues?  Let's see that code.

Comment: Updated my fiddle 'https://jsfiddle.net/3oup9Lg6/' . By "sometimes" i meant there are places when the page is resized and if the item values in various divs are fetched through service call so at times even before the call getting completed the calculation is done. I can ensure that the calculation happens after service calls but there are too many service calls and are async . I am very bad at explaining things but hope so you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- All the parents of **div2** needs to have 100% height, including **body** and **html**.
- Use `d-flex flex-column` on all parents of **div2** should they have more than 2 children.
- Use `flex-grow-1` on **div2** and all of its parents if they have more than two children.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.w-300px {
  width: 300px;
}

.h-200vh {
  height: 200vh;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow-auto {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
    <aside class="col-auto h-100 bg-danger overflow-auto">
      <div class="w-300px h-200vh"></div>
    </aside>
    <div class="col d-flex flex-column  h-100 ">
      <section class="row bg-info">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam labore sit at, distinctio velit veritatis atque officia ullam ducimus sapiente ad suscipit inventore impedit minus! Assumenda, modi? Commodi, voluptatum reiciendis?
      </section>
      <section class="row flex-grow-1 bg-primary overflow-auto">
        <div class="col">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, dolore. Sit quos, soluta temporibus debitis architecto fugit voluptas iusto exercitationem suscipit ea ex blanditiis, facere tempore, quo quidem quasi cum! Id natus iure magni molestiae!
          Iusto, quisquam molestias? Exercitationem consequatur voluptas accusamus eveniet magni facere mollitia natus quia neque, dolorum suscipit amet fugiat debitis, corrupti architecto, aliquid illo commodi quasi? Corporis illo doloribus voluptatem
          accusamus ullam ex dolores in illum architecto, inventore quam voluptate, mollitia eveniet quidem velit? Consequuntur ut totam delectus accusantium perspiciatis rem veniam eligendi enim expedita voluptate. Deserunt suscipit dignissimos, dolorum
          cum culpa molestias est totam dolores eius impedit enim temporibus architecto, cumque ipsam cupiditate tempore eveniet animi sed reiciendis? Illum fugiat, obcaecati tenetur veritatis vitae alias? Natus culpa, saepe fugiat error possimus mollitia,
          consectetur repellendus temporibus magnam ipsum nam maiores. Quisquam perspiciatis ea quos incidunt alias! Libero, deleniti. Esse dicta ducimus, tempore fugiat tenetur accusantium corporis? Odit numquam aut illum doloribus provident autem rerum
          iusto in natus soluta. Sed illum officia, perspiciatis magni ipsa aspernatur id voluptate molestias consequatur ad esse itaque facere soluta perferendis impedit. Sunt nihil, quasi hic beatae ipsa nostrum neque, necessitatibus quae cumque debitis
          impedit corrupti totam dignissimos eum ullam aut quam tempora perferendis recusandae consequatur, iste ratione veniam atque natus! Iusto? Nemo eveniet delectus fuga quibusdam quam non suscipit consequatur. Dolorum consequuntur ullam inventore
          iusto corrupti unde, sint consequatur nihil sequi perferendis mollitia tempore error debitis fuga vero! Non, eveniet temporibus. Deleniti nemo maiores error omnis magni magnam sapiente! Tenetur, debitis veniam cupiditate delectus assumenda dignissimos!
          Voluptatum qui cumque inventore ducimus reiciendis commodi, neque non voluptate aperiam tempore nobis quidem cum! Expedita obcaecati doloribus iusto possimus! A quae asperiores iure labore vero repudiandae, sint tenetur cupiditate ab nostrum.
          Laboriosam sunt iure repellendus repudiandae, veniam molestias animi itaque eveniet laudantium cum. Libero! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur quaerat eligendi quae excepturi perspiciatis, ipsum aliquid ipsa
          repudiandae fugiat, sunt maxime asperiores mollitia labore natus autem voluptatum, error voluptatem quisquam. Pariatur quas aliquam sequi nam iusto excepturi at quod illum cum asperiores, veniam cumque? Officia, assumenda! Sunt impedit minus
          molestias optio ea eum omnis quis aliquid commodi accusamus? Doloribus, facere. Vero veniam aliquam distinctio odit aspernatur hic repudiandae explicabo, sed odio aliquid consequuntur repellendus, molestias officiis quos sequi vitae ipsum perferendis
          accusantium possimus eaque porro quis inventore? Nemo, aliquid inventore. Qui molestiae distinctio temporibus dolore voluptas. Unde voluptatum velit fugiat error? Deleniti qui iusto aspernatur alias at dolore rerum consequuntur, nam vel inventore,
          nisi adipisci? Delectus nam expedita nemo tempora! Libero fuga eum quidem quisquam earum explicabo a quae dolorum, autem alias sequi dolores, velit amet voluptatibus atque veniam natus nam beatae. Laudantium similique maiores eos numquam quae
          qui sunt. Ea pariatur laboriosam eum illum maxime porro consequuntur error molestias. Et impedit, a exercitationem quibusdam tempora sit numquam laudantium incidunt quas voluptatem placeat, optio quisquam, obcaecati explicabo hic est iste. Officiis
          autem pariatur vitae tempora cum voluptatum amet sapiente dolorem quo corrupti nesciunt atque delectus veritatis, doloribus quis, nostrum et temporibus doloremque. Iure, similique fugiat. Odio eum nulla fugiat consequuntur. Est maxime aspernatur
          enim aperiam reiciendis saepe officia labore sunt, id fuga, repellendus doloribus? Repudiandae perferendis, veritatis, quidem maiores iste molestiae placeat soluta impedit iure accusantium quae. Ipsa, velit hic. Commodi eum possimus vitae veritatis
          earum! Vero dolorum repellendus, quam, deleniti doloribus tempore, aspernatur cum totam debitis voluptatum veritatis iure asperiores sapiente ea repudiandae dicta facilis reiciendis ut alias quibusdam. Nostrum unde tenetur, quaerat nisi sint
          quia debitis veritatis mollitia magni facere laboriosam aliquam id. Dolor, perferendis! Quia architecto eius laboriosam dolore at quas, optio, qui culpa placeat esse sint!
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Update;

- Use **overflow:auto;** on the elements that scroll, and **overflow:hidden;** on their parent. I changed the code :).

*This is similar to [Full page height for "select" via Bootstrap 4. How to get the page view on the image 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62449711/full-page-height-for-select-via-bootstrap-4-how-to-get-the-page-view-on-the-i/62451427#62451427) that I answered yerterday.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although there is a scroll on the page, i don't want a scroll. Refer https://jsfiddle.net/k5rg1fej/3/ . I just want a scroll inside the table and side bar